# Can we minify from the front-end of a web-app?

Tags: javascript, frontend, minify, uglifyjs

I want to export some code from my web-app (CSS and JS), so that when the user clicks on an 'export' button, he receive a ZIP file with `index.html`, `styles.css` and `script.js` files. How can I minify the `script.js` or/and the `styles.css` with javascript from the front-end ?
Thanks

Comment: Start by finding a minify library written in JS that is compatible with browsers … or write one from scratch.

Comment: try `Webpack.js`

Comment: Your code should _already_ be minified in the first place...

Comment: That is the whole point : I can't minify it at the first place because I create some code from within my web-app. If we talk about CSS for example, the user select some options regarding color, animation and all, I add the options as `<style>` tag in the `index.html` file created and I want to minify the CSS within the `<style>` from within my web-app.